# Share project between Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I have two solutions on my TFS source code control on VSTS. One with a UWP application and another with an Asp.net Core web project.

I have a third file that contains two class library projects.

I refer the project in the UWP, it works on my Visual Studio and on the build on VSTS.
For the project Asp.Net Core I also refer the project it compiles on my visual studio but on the VSTS build it fails while the path is the same but I have this error:

> The project file "D: \ a \ 3 \ s \ SharedLibrary \ KapseoPlus.Models \
>   KapseoPlus.Service \ KapseoPlus.Service.csproj" was not found.

I really do not see how to solve the problem and why on my computer it works perfectly but not on VSTS.

Comment: you haven't given much detail to allow us to help you but my guess is that you have added it as a existing project , on your local machine this works as you can reference the solution in the other solution, however TS doesn't use your local filesystem so can't resolve the address in the solution file, if you add the shared projects DLL in as a reference then TS will have a hard copy of the DLL to reference and it may help

Comment: Is there a strong reason not to have a single solution containing all 3 projects? If necessary, you can define configurations where only some projects are built.

Comment: Have you added that folder in the Get Sources / Workspace Mappings part of the build definition?

Comment: That's most probably the local file path doesn't maps with VSTS.

Comment: Thanks stuartd, the problem is solve ;)

Comment: we have a simple rule at work, if you your code does not build and run following a very simple 'get' from your source control then it needs work. Following this rule makes sure that you can `easily` use CI tools and allows other develops to just get on with coding if they need to work on your project.  I would look at git sub modules and NuGet as posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Create NuGet packages. Microsoft has made it almost stupidly simple at this point with the new .csproj format. You simply edit the properties of your class library project, go to the "Package" tab, check the "Generate NuGet package on build" box and fill out the appropriate information below. On build, then, a NuGet package will be created for your class library.

Since you're already using VSTS, you can install the [Package Management marketplace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed) to create a private NuGet feed. It's free for up to 5 users, with "users" being qualified as access to install from or push packages to your feed. You can then add your private feed as an additional source in the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio and easily install your private NuGets in any of your projects. Also, with VSTS, you can set up an automate build with continuous integration and an automate release to push new versions of your NuGets anytime you check in code. Then it's a simple matter of edit your class library, commit and push, and then within a few minutes, you can go over to your other projects and update. Easy peasy.

Comment: we just use git and sub modules, I agree that NuGet packages are a breeze but its also simple to just include a sub module and reference it.

Comment: @SteveDrake Depends on how familiar you are with Git. And in my experience, even experienced Git users find submodules to be a PITA.